# GND Pins are not connected to GND plane

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, ground-plane

Adding some components and a ground plane, all GND pins are connected automatically after a ratsnest command (just like `R2` in picture); except those that I added manually in my custom library (like the battery `B1` in picture). I wonder why I can't get them connected to the plane...

[image: example]

**Update:** Adding schematic to make sure:

[image: schematic]

Comment: Are you sure its "GND" pin is really "GND"? Please go to respective library you sourced device from, and examine pad names. Also can you connect this pin to GND net with wire in your schematic?

Comment: No, pad name is '-' as all other batteries in the builtin 'battery' library of eagle. Should I rename the pad and the pin to GND?

Comment: Could you upload the board and schematic files to [here](https://gist.github.com/) and add a link to them in your q.

Comment: @TomCarpenter https://gist.github.com/soroush/7a4d2dd4b0d7d20b8b7247ba3a358547 Also added my library

Comment: @sorush-r I've found the issue. Just writing an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing is due to a mistake in the library.

On examining your library it becomes apparent that you have placed a drill hole directly on top of your through-hole pad:

[image: Drill in pad]

If you delete the drill hole (through-hole pads have a drill hole already so don't need another), all works as expected:

[image: Connects fine]

You have the same problem on the hole for the `+` pin as well - an extra drill hole. If you run the DRC in eagle it will tell you the issue (`Error - close or overlapping holes` or something similar).

Comment: Thank you (: I don't know why I expected a through-hole pad, that was not a SMD, to need a drill hole! That sounds stupid saying it loudly :D

Answer (score 0):

> No, pad name is '-' as all other batteries in the builtin 'battery' library of eagle. Should I rename the pad and the pin to GND?

If you want some pad to be connected to some network, that pad should have identical name with than network. In your case you just need to explicitly connect "-" pad of the battery device to ground (GND) in your schematic.

You do NOT need to change pad name of the battery device (and it would be wrong action anyway, because + and - are correct names for the battery pads). You just need to ensure you connect battery device properly in your circuit.

Comment: I am sure that I connected the '-' pin into GND wire, as both the yellow airwire line in PCB board, and schematic claim. (See the update)

Comment: It looks like it just hasn't been routed yet.

Comment: @Finbarr  The battery is expected to connect automatically to the copper pour with spokes (like the R2 on the left).  The question is why it doesn't connect automatically.